# TypeError: 'float' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, loops, variables

I understand the message behind the error, but I got lost when understanding how to get over it. What I am trying to do is that in the for/loop the variable called `pancake` utilizes as input the value from the previous iteration `pancake[i - 1]` as first parameter of the function `exit` call.

Error I am experiencing:

```
TypeError: 'float' object does not support item assignment
```

My code:

```
   def exit(number):
        def son():
            geometric = (math.exp(2))
            pancake = number * geometric
            return pancake

        return son()

    pancake_ac = exit()()
    pancake_ac[0] = pancake_ac

    for i in range(1, 10):
        pancake_ac[i] = exit(pancake_ac[i - 1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`precio_accion` is not a `list` or `dict`, it's a float, so you don't need the `precio_accion[0] = precio_accion` line at all. If you want a `list`:

```py
import math
import random


def funcion_gbm(pi = 100, media = 0.10, volatilidad = 0.05):
    m = media
    v = volatilidad

    def funcion_anidada():
        exponencial = math.exp((m - (1/2) * v**2) * (1/365) +
                               v * math.sqrt(1/365) * random.normalvariate(0, 1))
        precio = pi * exponencial
        return precio

    return funcion_anidada


precio_accion = funcion_gbm()()

# Now precio_accion is a list and your iteration will work
precio_accion = [precio_accion]
```

### Edit

Now let's get into your loop. First, your `target_price` doesn't change, so why keep re-defining it? You can define it once outside of your loop:

```py
target_price = 125

for rueda in range(1,1000):
    # Now you need to append to the list rather than trying to
    # access other elements that aren't in the list yet
    precio_accion.append(funcion_gbm(precio_accion[rueda - 1]))

    # You're comparing the last item in the list every time, so
    # you can just access it with -1
    if precio_accion[-1] == target_price:
        print("reached")

    # No need for else since it's just continuing the loop
```